# Storing ranges in array with JSONB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, range, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb

I've set the attribute `data` to JSONB type in the migration:

```
t.jsonb  :data, null: false, default: {}
```

When trying to save the following:

```
my_object.data = [1..3, 5..7]
my_object.save
```

The ranges are converted to strings:

```
my_object.data
=> ["1..3", "5..7"]
```

Is there any way to work with array of ranges with JSONB?

Comment: convert those ranges to arrays and store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only storing ranges you can override the getter of `data`

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  def data
    super.map do |str|
      Range.new(*str.split("..").map(&:to_i))
    end
  end
end
```